# Rails - Is Sendmail or Postfix Installation required for External SMTP Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sendmail, actionmailer, sendgrid

So I use Sendgrid, an external SMTP server handling transaction emails.

I just deployed my Rails app on a fresh new VPS, with Ubuntu on it.

In [Sendgrid tutorial](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html), I saw that I only have to set ActionMailer to point to sendgrid's SMTP address with proper username/password.

But I was met with `Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25` error, but I am sure I have set it to point to Sendgrid's 587 port. I searched online and someone suggested me to install postfix. I am guessing ActionMailer need a MTA on localhost.

**Is sendmail or postfix a required package for using external SMTP service on Linux?**

Comment: Could you show SMTP config?

Comment: Could you show the config.action_mailer.delivery_method setting?

Comment: And config.action_mailer.default_url_options settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, postfix or sendmail is not required.

ActionMailer/Mailer gem can connect to remote SMTP server directly.

---

As a side note, my localhost issue is that the keys of the config hash were somehow converted into String keys. Converting it to symbol keys fixed the issue.